# Recursion and "Return" Statements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

Beginner javascript-er here...

I came across a problem where I had to use use recursion to find out whether a given number (n) is even.  Here was my solution - which passes all tests - but I'm wondering on one piece where the word "return" is needed - see below comments:

```
var isEven = function(n) {
  if (n < 0){
    n = Math.abs(n);
  }

  if(n === 1){
    return false;
  } else if (n === 0){
    return true;
  } else {
    return isEven(n-2);  // here is my question - can you explain why does this need the 'return' in there?
  }
};
```

Comment: Without that you wouldn't have a return value when `n > 1` so the function would just return `undefined` instead of `true` or `false`.

Comment: That is where you have the recursive call.. So yes, you need it..

Comment: You didn't test your function with a decimal number ...

Answer (score 3):

> here is my question - can you explain why does this need the 'return' in there?

It has to do with function calls, and how the results of a function are passed back to the caller.

Forget recursion for a moment, and lets look at a pair of functions.

```
function foo() {
  return 'foo for you';
}

function bar() {
  foo();
}
```

What happens if I call `bar()` like so:

```
console.log(bar());
```

Expected output:

```
'undefined'
```

`foo()` is executed, but the results of the functional call are ignored (e.g. not saved to a variable, nor returned). bar() has no explict return statement, so by the ECMA specification, an implicit `return undefined;` is used.

Looking at the call stack (note that this is written like a stack datastructure with the current function call at the top of the stack):

```
foo() ==> returns 'foo for you'
bar() ==> returns 'undefined'
```

Which results in `undefined` being passed into the console output function.

If we modify `bar()` like so:

```
function bar() {
 return foo();
}
```

Our output changes to:

```
'foo for you'
```

The result of `foo()` is returned as the result of `bar()` examining the call stack

```
foo() ==> returns 'foo for you'
bar() ==> returns foo() which returns 'foo for you'
```

Going back to your recursive example, without the return statement, it will execute, but the results of that execution won't be passed up the call stack.

Let's pretend the return statement is missing, and inspect the callstack, when n = 4.

```
isEven(0) ==> returns true
isEven(2) ==> returns undefined
isEven(4) ==> returns undefined
```

`isEven(4) = undefined. ERROR.`

The ultimate expected value, `true` never gets passed up the callstack.

As written, with the return value, this is the result:

```
isEven(0) ==> returns true
isEven(2) ==> returns isEven(0) which returns true
isEven(4) ==> returns isEven(2) which returns isEven(0) which returns true
```

`isEven(4) = true PASSED.`

Answer (score 1):

`isEven(n - 2)` is called, and evaluated.

Once it finishes, the caller function takes its evaluation, and returns it back -- to its caller.

Answer (score 1):

Through the recursive call you get "up" the callstack:

```
--> isEven(6) --> isEven(4) --> isEven(2) --> isEven(0)
```

Now you `return true` from the upper call:

```
--> isEven(6) --> isEven(4) --> isEven(2) --> isEven(0)
  ? <--                                   <-- true
```

But that does not reach the original caller yet. So we have to return it from `isEven(2)` and so on so that it reaches the caller:

```
--> isEven(6) --> isEven(4) --> isEven(2) --> isEven(0)
 true <-     <--           <--           <--
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is a multi-paradigm language, and as such, you can write valid JavaScript programs in a variety of styles.

In older JavaScript programs, functions could only be declared using `function` syntax which defined a function body between two curly braces, `{ ... }`.

The function body is made up of *statements*. One such statement is the `return` statement which allows a function to return a value. Without the `return` statement, a function will always return `undefined`.

So from one perspective you can say "You need a `return` statement otherwise you will get `undefined`", but from another perspective you could say "You're using `function` syntax, so you must use `return` if you expect a return value".

The alternative is a syntax available to you in newer JavaScript programs (ES6 and up), called [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Arrow functions can accept a traditional function body with statements just like we talked about above. But arrow functions can also be written using a single *expression* as the body, where the `return` is implied

```
// function syntax
var f = function () { return 1 }

// arrow syntax with body
var f = () => { return 1 }

// arrow syntax with implied return   
var f = () => 1
```

If you can manage to write your function using an expression, you don't have to worry about all of the strange behaviors associated with statements like `return`.

To make logical decisions below, we use a [ternary expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). Unlike the `if` statement, a ternary *expression* evaluates to a value, which when coupled with an arrow function, we can imagine the logical branches as each having their own implicit `return` ...

```js
const isEven = (n) =>
  n === 0
    ? true         // implicit return
  
  : n === 1
    ? false        // implicit return
  
  : isEven (n - 2) // implicit return
  
console.log
  ( isEven (0)  // true
  , isEven (1)  // false
  , isEven (2)  // true
  , isEven (3)  // false
  , isEven (4)  // true
  , isEven (5)  // false
  )
```

Of course that's just one way. Here's another

```js
const isEven = (n) =>
  n < 2
    ? !Boolean (n)
    : isEven (n - 2)

console.log
  ( isEven (0)  // true
  , isEven (1)  // false
  , isEven (2)  // true
  , isEven (3)  // false
  , isEven (4)  // true
  , isEven (5)  // false
  )
```

And another using [mutual recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion)

```js
const isEven = (n) =>
  n === 0
    ? true
    : isOdd (n - 1)
    
const isOdd = (n) =>
  n === 0
    ? false
    : isEven (n - 1)

console.log
  ( isEven (0)  // true
  , isEven (1)  // false
  , isEven (2)  // true
  , isEven (3)  // false
  , isEven (4)  // true
  , isEven (5)  // false
  )
  
console.log
  ( isOdd (0)  // false
  , isOdd (1)  // true
  , isOdd (2)  // false
  , isOdd (3)  // true
  , isOdd (4)  // false
  , isOdd (5)  // true
  )
```