# how to use if statement when property is null

Tags: javascript, algorithm, if-statement, recursion, binary-tree

I have a simple if statement as shown.  However,the recursive statement eventually doesn't have a val value and rather than execute the rest of my code windows powershell just exists with TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of null.

```
chkL = (L) => {
    if(L.left.val) chkL(L.left);
}
```

Here is the full code:

```
function TreeNode(val) {
    this.val = val;
    this.left = this.right = null;
}

let tree1 = new TreeNode(1);
tree1.left = new TreeNode(3);
tree1.right = new TreeNode(2);
tree1.left.left = new TreeNode(5);

let tree2 = new TreeNode(2);
tree2.left = new TreeNode(1);
tree2.right = new TreeNode(3);
tree2.left.right = new TreeNode(4);
tree2.right.right = new TreeNode(7);

var mergeTrees = function(t1, t2) {
    let ans = Object.assign({}, t1);

    chkL = (L) => {
        if(L.left.val) chkL(L.left);
    }

    if(t1.left.val) {
        chkL(t1.left);
    }


};

mergeTrees(tree1, tree2);
```

I'm wondering if there's a way I can use something like eval() or try catch in the if statement to stop the script from breaking?  Note, I know I can simply remove the .val part of the logic however I'm only curious about how to execute code similar to this.

Comment: change to if(t1.left && t1.left.val)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use something like this:

```
if (t1.left && t1.left.val) {
  // do stuff
}
```

this if statement just evaluates to false if property val does not exist on object left, and won't break.

Comment: This works.  I was just wondering if there's some nifty command I'm unaware of.

Comment: @user2101 this isn't PHP where you can just suppress legitimate errors with `@` :P

Comment: @user2101 the problem you're having is a symptom of the way you've approached the problem. If you want to avoid this burden, see my answer for details

Answer (score 0):

Using ES6 destructuring:

```
const chkL = ({ left, left: { val } = {} }) => {
    if (val) {
        chkL(left);
    }
    // the invisible last line in all JS functions
    return undefined;
}
```

Now this function can be written much simpler one that does the same:

```
const chkL = () => undefined;
```

Comment: The *"invisible last line"* in all `function { statements; }` and `() => { statements; }` functions. But not `() => ...`. I nitpick because I wrote about this [earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50748728/633183) :D

Comment: @user633183 But `() => expression` is just syntax sugar for `() => { return expression; return undefined; }`. It might still be there in the engine, but never used.

Comment: Understood. I comment because it seems more people suffer from implicit `return` than is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
L.left ? chkL(L.left) : "else condition"
```

You could add else condition if you need to

Answer (score 0):

**recursion is functional**

Recursion is a functional heritage and so writing your program in a functional style will yield the best results. This means avoiding mutations, null checks, and other side effects. Instead of butchering your code, I'm just going to hope that a different program makes it clear that there's better ways to solve this problem...

We start with `Empty` and `Node`

```
const Empty =
  {}

const Node = (value, left = Empty, right = Empty) =>
  ({ value, left, right })
```

And a way to `merge` two nodes

```
const merge = (n1, n2) =>
  n1 === Empty
    ? n2

  : n2 === Empty
    ? n1

  : Node ( n1.value + n2.value // some merging operation!
         , merge (n1.left, n2.left)
         , merge (n1.right, n2.right)
         )
```

Now we take two trees, `t1` and `t2`

```
const t1 =
  Node ('A'
       , Node ('B')
       , Node ('C', Node ('D'), Node ('E'))
       )

const t2 =
  Node ('a'
       , Node ('b', Node ('x'))
       , Node ('c'
              , Node ('d', Node ('y'))
              )
       )
```

To see what's going on, we add some function to `print` the trees

```
const print = (node, pre = '', child = '') =>
  node === Empty
    ? ""
    : print (node.left, child + '┌── ', child + '.   ')
      + pre + String (node.value) + '\n'
      + print (node.right, child + '└── ', child + '.   ')

console.log (print (t1)
// ┌── B
// A
// .   ┌── D
// └── C
// .   └── E

console.log (print (t2))
// .   ┌── x
// ┌── b
// a
// .   .   ┌── y
// .   ┌── d
// └── c
```

Now for the celebration - Note, neither `t1` nor `t2` are changed as a result of calling `merge`. A brand-new `t3` is formed.

```
const t3 =
  merge (t1, t2)

console.log (print (t3))
// .   ┌── x
// ┌── Bb
// Aa
// .   .   ┌── y
// .   ┌── Dd
// └── Cc
// .   └── E
```

Run the complete program in your browser below

```js
const Empty =
  {}

const Node = (value, left = Empty, right = Empty) =>
  ({ value, left, right })
  
const merge = (n1, n2) =>
  n1 === Empty
    ? n2
  
  : n2 === Empty
    ? n1
    
  : Node ( n1.value + n2.value // some merging function!
         , merge (n1.left, n2.left)
         , merge (n1.right, n2.right)
         )

const print = (node, pre = '', child = '') =>
  node === Empty
    ? ""
    : print (node.left, child + '┌── ', child + '.   ')
      + pre + String (node.value) + '\n'
      + print (node.right, child + '└── ', child + '.   ')

const t1 =
  Node ('A'
       , Node ('B')
       , Node ('C', Node ('D'), Node ('E'))
       )
       
const t2 =
  Node ('a'
       , Node ('b', Node ('x'))
       , Node ('c'
              , Node ('d', Node ('y'))
              )
       )
       
console.log (print (t1))
// ┌── B
// A
// .   ┌── D
// └── C
// .   └── E

console.log (print (t2))
// .   ┌── x
// ┌── b
// a
// .   .   ┌── y
// .   ┌── d
// └── c

const t3 =
  merge (t1, t2)

console.log (print (t3))
// .   ┌── x
// ┌── Bb
// Aa
// .   .   ┌── y
// .   ┌── Dd
// └── Cc
// .   └── E
```

**functional means flexible**

Obvious improvements to this program would involve making `merge` a higher-order function such that `+` is not hard-coded into our program

```
// improved merge; user-defined merging function, f
const merge = (f, n1, n2) =>
  n1 === Empty
    ? n2

  : n2 === Empty
    ? n1

  : Node ( f (n1.value, n2.value) // <---
         , merge (f, n1.left, n2.left)
         , merge (f, n1.right, n2.right)
         )
```

Now the caller of `merge` can define how values are combined. In this example, we put both values into an array

```
const t4 =
  merge ((v1,v2) => [v1, v2], t1, t2)

console.log (print (t4))
// .   ┌── x
// ┌── B,b
// A,a
// .   .   ┌── y
// .   ┌── D,d
// └── C,c
// .   └── E
```

Now when we `print` the tree, the arrays are converted to strings. Another obvious improvement here would be to tweak our `print` function similar to what we did with `merge`, allowing the user to specify *how* values are printed

```
// improved print; String is no longer hard-coded
const print = (node, fmt = String, pre = '', child = '') =>
  node === Empty
    ? ""
    : print (node.left, fmt, child + '┌── ', child + '.   ')
      + pre + fmt (node.value) + '\n' // <---
      + print (node.right, fmt, child + '└── ', child + '.   ')
```

Now we can specify our formatting function as a second argument

```
console.log (print (t4, JSON.stringify)) // print as JSON!
// .   ┌── "x"
// ┌── ["B","b"]
// ["A","a"]
// .   .   ┌── "y"
// .   ┌── ["D","d"]
// └── ["C","c"]
// .   └── "E"
```

In the trees above, we output `""` for `Empty` nodes. Maybe we'd like a way to visualize them, so we can modify the `print` function one more time

```
// improved print; displays Empty nodes as ∅
const print = (node, fmt = String, pre = '', child = '') =>
  node === Empty
    ? pre + '\u2205\n' // <---
    : print (node.left, fmt, child + '┌── ', child + '.   ')
      + pre + fmt (node.value) + '\n'
      + print (node.right, fmt, child + '└── ', child + '.   ')

console.log (print (t3))
// .   .   ┌── ∅
// .   ┌── x
// .   .   └── ∅
// ┌── Bb
// .   └── ∅
// Aa
// .   .   .   ┌── ∅
// .   .   ┌── y
// .   .   .   └── ∅
// .   ┌── Dd
// .   .   └── ∅
// └── Cc
// .   .   ┌── ∅
// .   └── E
// .   .   └── ∅
```