# changing my array while iterating over it (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, iteration, mutation

Apologies I wrote my earlier question in a bit of a haste so couldn't phrase it properly with correct example.

The problem below has cropped up a number of times and I am always stuck. My knowledge of Javascript is beginner level only.

I want my array list to mutate and change while iterating over it.
Essentially, iterating over the entirely new array gained from first iteration.

```
arr = [ 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4 ]

if arr[n]== 1 and arr[n+1] == 2 || arr[n] == 3 || arr[n+1] == 4
then remove arr[n] and arr[n+1] and current index is +2 else
newarr.push[n] and current index is +1
Loop over
```

After the above loop runs we get:

```
newarr = [1, 2, 4, 4];
```

Now loop runs over this new array with the same condition. We get

```
newarr = [4,4];
```

Now since the condition cannot be met, we break out of loop.

Hope this is clearer. I have tried everything but the loop always refers to the original array and I just do not know how to make it use the resulting array. Is this something that can be done by recursion or maybe the reduce method?

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Be careful removing elements from an array while you're iterating over it. The indexes of all the following elements will shift down, which could cause your iteration to skip elements. It's usually best to iterate from the end instead of the beginning.

Comment: Why does `2, 15, 6, 7` turn to `2, 21, 7`? Your rule does not modify any value right?

Comment: @KentaNomoto You are right. My example was not clearer. I have updated my question, please have a look. The rules do modify the value. Loop should always use the resulting array from previous iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use recursion.

Everytime you call `change_array()` you pass as argument the array that you want to be modified.

The first time you call this function you supply the original array.
This function creates a new array,takes the needed elements from the old array and calls itself again with the new array as parameter.This continues until no more modifications are made to the array.

When you have a recursive function you should also have a condition that stops recursion to avoid infinite calls and stack overflows.

In this particular example if no modifications are made to the array, because no matching element was found according to our criteria, we stop recursion in this line

```
if(!found_element){ return false;}
```

Here is the full code

```
var original_arr = [ 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4 ];
change_array(original_arr);

function change_array(arr){

var temp_array=[];
var found_element=false;

console.log(arr);

for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

    if((arr[i]==1 && arr[i+1]==2 )|| (arr[i]==3 && arr[i+1]==4)){
        found_element=true;
        i++;
    }else{
        temp_array.push(arr[i]);
    }
}

if(!found_element){ return false;}

change_array(temp_array);

}
```

when executed returns

```
[1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 4, 4]
[4, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did consider recursion. I understand the logic behind recursion but it's practical application beats me. I will certainly take and implement your solution above today and come back. In the mean time, if you get a minute please do go through y updated question just now. Thanks again.

Comment: @amars I modified my code to work according to your modified question.Keep in mind that the basic principle is the same as before.

Comment: It's beautiful and sublime the way it works and the way you have used the boolean and increment the i twice when a match is found. Just a question though. When if(!found_element){ return false;}
returns false. How does the previous function receive the boolean from this line? Where does this boolean go?

Comment: @amars in this example we use `return false;` just to stop recursion.It isnt really needed.I just thought it would be more easy to understand.You could just replace with `if(found_element){
change_array(temp_array);
}` and will work the same because by default if you ommit return, it will return undefined.So in my answer return false is returned only once in the last call.You can check this answer for more info on the subject https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50732969/recursion-and-return-statements-in-javascript